# Java - How To Synchronize 2 Threads On 1 List?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

How can I synchronize 2 threads to handle data in a list ?

- **thread A** is adding / changing items in a list (writing to the list)
- **thread B** is displaying the items (only reading the list)

I would like to "notify" **thread B** when it can display the list. In the time of reading the list it must not be changed by **thread A**. When **thread B** is done reading, **thread A** can start changing the list again.

My guesses go to

- `synchronized(obj)`
- `list.wait()` + `list.notify()`

Threads aren't invoking each other. They run concurrent all the time.

Comment: Can you show a little bit of code that you plan to use?

Comment: why don't you just synchronize the methods which is using the data in that list?

Comment: Duplicated Thread.
Refer to <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444005/how-do-i-make-my-arraylist-thread-safe-another-approach-to-problem-in-java>

Comment: @gurvinder372 Logvinov When I synchronize methods I end up in dead locks. I guess I'm doing something wrong and my project is too big to post in forums. So I would like to see a general concept of synchronizing 2 threads on data in Java.

Comment: @Andrew Logvinov see my comment above

Comment: are these two methods readList or updateList invoking each other, since then it could cause deadlock?

Comment: @gurvinder372 No. But my project is too big to be sure about anything. I guess that's a bad sign right ?

Comment: It sure is a sign of bad design. Please get in touch with your architect and understand the overall design first, isolate the problem and then revert with a clear question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried concurrency packages suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1537133/1442225) or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) and it works well. The threads lock each other out:

```
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

// thread A
lock.lock();
// write to list
lock.unlock();

// thread B
lock.lock();
// read from list
lock.unlock();
```

Not sure if they can execute precisely one after another and I didn't get the notify feature. But that doesn't hurt my application.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all changes in Runnables and put them in a queue that Thread A executes in order. After each job, A must generate a snapshot of the modified list and submit it to Thread B. You could use Executors for that.

Answer (score 0):

General concept (as I see it in your case) would be as follows.

1) Create an instance of `List` that you're planning to work with.

2) Write 2 classes corresponding to your `thread A` and `thread B` that both implement `Runnable` and take `List` as their constructor parameter.

3) Synchronize these 2 classes on list instance:

```
// method in class that adds
public void add() {
  synchronized(list) {
    // perform addition ...
    list.notify();
  }
}

// method in class that reads
public void read() throws InterruptedException {
  synchronized(list) {
    while (list.isEmpty())
      list.wait();
    // process data ...
  }
}
```

4) Create 2 threads with argumens corresponding to instances of these 2 classes and start them.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do but always ended up in deadlocks, IllegalMonitoExceptions or unsynchronized execution. I'll go with ReentrantLock since it works well.

Answer (score 0):

[Reader and writer locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) are your friends here.

> •thread A is adding / changing items in a list (writing to the list)

... so it can use the write lock ...

> •thread B is displaying the items (only reading the list)

... so it can use the read lock.

Let's assume that you're using something straight forward for your wait/notify (for example, the built-in [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) methods) to block the read and display thread.  At that point, your code looks something like this:

```
/** This is the read/write lock that both threads can see */
private ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

/** This method is called by thread A (the writer / modifier) */
public void add() {
    try {
        // Only one writer at a time allowed
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        // Insert code here: Add to the list 
    } finally {
        // Unlock in the finally block to ensure that lock is released
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
    // Notify anyone who's waiting for data
    list.notify();
}

/** This method is called by thread B (the reader / displayer) */
public void read() throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        // As many readers as you like at a time
        lock.readLock().lock();
        // Insert code here: read from the list
    } finally {
        // Unlock in the finally block to ensure that lock is released
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
    // Wait for new data
    list.wait();
}
```

To make things even more convenient, you can get rid of the notify/wait messaging by using a blocking data structure: e.g., one of the [BlockingQueues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).  In that case, you don't write any notification at all.  The reader blocks waiting for new data.  When the writer adds data to the queue, the reader unblocks, drains the new data to process, does its thing and then blocks again.

Comment: Interesting. But the Q was simpler (to just synchronize reader and writer). Or does this have some benefits over the simple ReentrantLock ?

Comment: @mini-me, yes, if you have a situation where readers and writers are not balanced: e.g., more readers than writers, writing takes less time than reading or other examples.  There's extra logic in the read/write locks: arbitrary numbers of readers vs. only one writer, no more readers if a writer requests a lock, etc.